# Magento 2 Rest API Shipping

Tags: magento2, shipping, rest-api

I am currently trying to integrate Magento with an already existing ERP system. It is going well so far except I have a problem when I am trying to ship an order.

I need Magento to ignore quantity when I am Shipping order via Rest API as quantity is getting an update from ERP system and not on Magento itself.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do that?

Thanks in advance!
Eddie

Comment: Do you mean every item's quantity should shown as 0 while order is placed from Rest API? May be I am guessing it wrong